# Is passing parameters expensive?

Tags: c#, performance, xna

I have a method that draws tiles onto the screen, and inside this method there is a call to a method in the same class called drawFloor which draws specific tiles.

In the external method, I started a stop watch right above the drawFloor call and stopped it right below the call, and the time I got was 2.4 milliseconds.

Then I put the stop watch inside the actual drawFloor method itself, making the stopwatch embody all the code in the method, and the time I got was 1.9 milliseconds.

The only thing that I think could be making this change in time is the passing of parameters, and I don't understand why it's so expensive. It only passes two parameters, one to a custom class called "camera" and also a sprite batch.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Was this "timing" done in a debug build, or inside of the VS hosting process?

Comment: @DanWebster Were you running in VS?

Comment: @Reed yes, visual studio debugging

Comment: @DanWebster You'll find that method call transitions are far more expensive, and timings are very irregular, if you run that way.  If you do a release build and run outside of the VS host (ie: Ctrl+F5 instead of F5), the timings will be completely different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's really not that expensive. It's almost certainly just a discrepancy in your measurements. Good micro-benchmarking is hard; it's entirely possible that you've done something else which changes things, or perhaps your machine is just less busy doing other things.

Method calls and parameter passing are *not* expensive - certainly not to the tune of half a millisecond.